# Swift cellForRowAt not displaying

Tags: ios, swift

I'm having problems making cellForRowAt work, but unfortunately my application remains blank after compiling it. I'm using Xcode 8.3 beta 3.

```
import UIKit

class myCell: UITableViewCell {

  @IBOutlet var myLabel: UILabel!
  @IBOutlet var myImageView: UIImageView!
  override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code
}

override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    // Configure the view for the selected state
  }
}
```

I've created a Food class to make the job easier:

```
import Foundation

class Food {
var imageName = ""
var description = ""
var moreInfo = ""

init(imageName: String, description: String, moreInfo: String) {
    self.imageName = imageName
    self.description = description
    self.moreInfo = moreInfo
  }
}
```

And finally, this is the TableViewController:

```
import UIKit

class TableViewController: UITableViewController {

    var foodArray: [Food] = [Food]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let food1 = Food(imageName: "cake.jpg", description: "Chocolate Cake", moreInfo: "There is nothing better than a great chocolate cake.")
        let food2 = Food(imageName: "meringue.jpg", description: "Meringue & Berries", moreInfo: "I really don't like meringue but it's a nice photo.")
        let food3 = Food(imageName: "peaches.jpg", description: "Grilled Peaches", moreInfo: "This would be perfect as a summer time dessert.")
        let food4 = Food(imageName: "tiramisu.jpg", description: "Tiramisu", moreInfo: "One of my favorite Italian desserts. Yum.")

        foodArray.append(food1)
        foodArray.append(food2)
        foodArray.append(food3)
        foodArray.append(food4)

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }



    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return foodArray.count
    }


    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! myCell
        let foodItem = foodArray[indexPath.row]
        cell.myImageView.image = UIImage(named: foodItem.imageName)
        cell.myLabel.text = foodItem.description
        self.tableView.reloadData()
        return cell
    }
}
```

Could anyone please show me what I've did wrong?

Comment: Is the method firing? Or are you saying the entire screen is blank? Because the latter is a different problem.

Comment: The application is blank

Comment: I'd take @reinier Melian's suggestions, except remove every reloadData() call, entirely. Let me know whether that works. reloadData() calls all of the data source methods of your table view, and you may have a loop here. Also, for future reference, UI updates should be run on the main thread.

Comment: @Virtuoso can you check your array count once in numberofRowsInSection?

Comment: Also tried to run without any reloadData(), but the application is still blank

Comment: @Virtuoso can you change your food class variables into type string instead of (var imageName = "") do  var imageName:String? and test once.

Comment: @TusharSharma Tried to return 1 as to test the function, but the application remains blank

Comment: change your variable declaraton once have you connected datasource and delegate properly? from storybord???

Comment: @Virtuoso check datasource and delegate connection once or add an image here of your connections.

Comment: Okay, two quick tests to run, but I think your problem is not the table view: put breakpoints or print statements in numberOfRowsInSection (@TusharSharma's suggestion) and cellForRowAtIndexPath, to make sure that these methods are firing, and returning proper values. I think you're likely not loading the entire VC properly, and figuring out whether these methods are firing, will help to narrow down the reason why.

Comment: Yes,they are properly connected and changing the variable declaration didn't make any change... I'm getting the output in the console : 2017-03-11 17:31:05.929 yummyDesserts[3297:968937] Unknown class TableViewController in Interface Builder file.

Comment: have you given your tableviewcontroller your class name in storyboard??

Comment: yes I did, I suppose this is a Swift bug

Comment: Fixed it, forgot to specify the Module "yummyDesserts"

Comment: So, EVERY SINGLE TIME I've seen that error, it's been because the IB class is wrong, or the Module name is wrong.

Comment: Ah, you beat me to it.

Comment: well that is a good news.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not call `self.tableView.reloadData()` inside your `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell` your `self.tableView.reloadData()`

replace your viewDidLoad method for this code

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let food1 = Food(imageName: "cake.jpg", description: "Chocolate Cake", moreInfo: "There is nothing better than a great chocolate cake.")
    let food2 = Food(imageName: "meringue.jpg", description: "Meringue & Berries", moreInfo: "I really don't like meringue but it's a nice photo.")
    let food3 = Food(imageName: "peaches.jpg", description: "Grilled Peaches", moreInfo: "This would be perfect as a summer time dessert.")
    let food4 = Food(imageName: "tiramisu.jpg", description: "Tiramisu", moreInfo: "One of my favorite Italian desserts. Yum.")

    foodArray.append(food1)
    foodArray.append(food2)
    foodArray.append(food3)
    foodArray.append(food4)
}
```

and use this code for your `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell`code

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! myCell
    let foodItem = foodArray[indexPath.row]
    cell.myImageView.image = UIImage(named: foodItem.imageName)
    cell.myLabel.text = foodItem.description
    return cell
  }
```

I hope this helps you

Comment: There is no reason to call reloadData() in viewDidLoad() (data source methods are called after viewWillAppear, I believe). Good catch on the reloadData() call in cellForRowAtIndexPath, however.

Comment: @Virtuoso was module name problem then?, still you should not call reloadData() in cellForRowAtIndexPath

Comment: yes I know now, I've searched my problem before posting a question and people said that in this case I should call reloadData(), but since I'm a beginner I didn't know where to call it, now I do. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to register the class and add a reuse identifier using the method:

```
tableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
```

Add this method in `viewDidLoad`

Also, you do not need to call `self.tableView.reloadData()` inside `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're calling `reloadData()` so to fix that, remove it from your code:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! myCell
    let foodItem = foodArray[indexPath.row]
    cell.myImageView.image = UIImage(named: foodItem.imageName)
    cell.myLabel.text = foodItem.description

    return cell
}
```